# Native gallery sorting is ignored

Tags: images, gallery, sort

On my website, I recently got a quite strange problem. I used to upload images via the nextGen Plugin. But since with this plugin google doesn't seem to index my pictures, I wanted to switch back to the native gallery.

So, naturally, I started to recreate the galleries step by step. A week ago, this worked just fine. Today suddenly all the sorting settings are ignored. Sort by menu, sort by title etc. are not visible. I emptied my cache a few times, but the problem doens't seem to be cache related.

Any help would be nice. The website in question is http://www.dreadfactory.de

**Update:**

Plugins that may effect the images are:
"Lightbox 2", "NextGEN Gallery". The cache plugin used is "W3 Total Cache". If I deactivate all of them, the error persists.

Apart from that, the only script I installed manually is "TJK_ToggleDL.js", to toggle list elements.

The rest of my plugins should not effect the gallery:

"Qtranslate", "Redirection", "Post Type order", "Wp-beautifier", "WP google+", "Ultimate Security Checker", "Google XML Sitemaps", "Exclude Pages from Navigation", "Contact Form 7", "Captcha", "Broken Link Checker", "Block Bad Queries", "Better WordPress Minify", "All in One SEO Pack

**Update 2**

The Shortcode is [gallery link="file" orderby="title"]

Comment: Are the sort options not visible in the UI or is WordPress ignoring the sort order you set?

Comment: Everything looks normal in the UI. It's ignoring the sort order I set.

Comment: Just to double-check, if you set the sort order to random and reload a few times, does the ordering change? Can you tell what IS the sort order?

Comment: I tried the random option but even with the option random, the order doesn't change. It's now set to order by title (increasing). The gallery is: http://www.dreadfactory.de/galerie/dreadlocks/anke-k/

Comment: The fact that there's a lightbox script means you're not *solely* using the core [gallery] shortcode. What plugins are you using or did you do something custom?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot, that I did install two plugins. One is "Gallery Custom Link", which simply adds a field with which you can add an external link for a picture and another one is "Lightbox 2" which adds a Lightbox wherever it finds images.

Comment: I deactivated both of them. No change. :/

Comment: Ok. Please update your question to include the plugins, any styles or scripts you're manually using, the shortcode you're using, and any other details that might affect this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3441/discussion-between-mrwweb-and-marvin-pollock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem was caused by the plugin "Post Types Order". It takes control over all post orders including the order within galleries. Since there does not seem to be an option to exclude galleries properly, you will have to deactivate the plugin to have control over the gallery order again.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem in "Post Types Order" plugin:

Add:

```
//ignore attachments
if ($query->query_vars['post_type']=='attachment') {
    return $orderBy;
}
```

On top in CPTOrderPosts() function.